# Java Swing buttons to make them equal

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MathsTutorProgram
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        JFrame a = new JFrame(); //Create a blank window
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Create a panel

        //Buttons
        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welome to Maths Tutor!");
        JButton lessThan = new JButton ("<");
        JButton greaterThan = new JButton (">");
        JButton equals = new JButton ("=");
        JButton askMe = new JButton ("Ask me a question!");

        //panels
        panel.add(welcome);
        panel.add(lessThan);
        panel.add(greaterThan);
        panel.add(equals);
        panel.add(askMe);
        a.setContentPane(panel); //Use panel on Window

        //sets
        a.setTitle("Maths Tutor Program"); //Change window title
        a.setSize(300,200); //Change window size
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.setVisible(true);

        //Border layout + Location
        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        panel.add("North", welcome);
        panel.add("East", equals);
        panel.add("South", askMe);
        panel.add("West", lessThan);
        panel.add("Center", greaterThan);
    }
}
```

I have working java swing. My <, > and = buttons are not the same size.
Centre button '=' is bigger than East '>' button and West button '<'.
Do I have to use gridlayout or can I still make three middle buttons same size using boarderlayout?
How can I make these three buttons same size regardless of the window size?

**Update**

```
//Border layout + Location
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    panel.add("North", welcome);
    panel.add("South", askMe);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
    buttonPanel.add(lessThan);
    buttonPanel.add(equals);
    buttonPanel.add(greaterThan);
    panel.add(buttonPanel);
```

Fixed the code.
East, west and centre buttons (<, >, and =) are averaged to same size regardless of the window size.

Comment: Since you set your panel's layout as BorderLayout, even if you set specific dimension for your button objects, they will still try to fit in their specified borders. I suggest you to try another layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Add the three buttons to one panel. Add that panel to the center. The `BorderLayout` you are using doesn't respect the preferred sizes of the buttons you are adding. So they get stretched. But if you add them to a `JPanel` with a default `FlowLayout`, the preferred sizes of the buttons *will* be respected. Also, `setVisible(true)` should be the *last* thing you do.

```
    panel.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(askMe, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.add(lessThan);
    centerPanel.add(greaterThan);
    centerPanel.add(equals);
    JPanel justToCenterPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    justToCenterPanel.add(centerPanel);
    panel.add(justToCenterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also note, the add method you are using is deprecated. Use `add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER)` instead

[image]

Comment: Without an appropriate layout for that panel (e.g. a `GridLayout(1,3)`) the buttons will still not have the same size...

Comment: @Marco13, they look fine to me

Comment: You're right. You did not mention the `GridBagLayout` first. They might have different sizes, but it seems like the characters `>`, `=` and `<` coincidentally have exactly the same width in the default font ;-)

Comment: @Marco13 I only added the `GridBagLayout` to center it. It would still be the same size without it, and just the default flow.

Comment: Again, I think this is a coincidence. It the contents of the buttons was different (or used a different Font, maybe even depending on the L&F?), their size would be different. But I think that the actual question was answered, so this is probably not important any more.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Noticed too late that you used a BorderLayout. In this case, see peeskillet's answer above ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912257 )

A very pragmatic solution would be something like

```
greaterThan.setPreferredSize(lessThan.getPreferredSize());
equals.setPreferredSize(lessThan.getPreferredSize());
```

to make them both as large as the `lessThan` button (or use an manually created, custom-sized `Dimension`). But you should also consider other LayoutManagers. The default (`FlowLayout`) does not offer much flexibility. In this example, you could add the three buttons to a `JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));` or so.

Comment: _"The default (FlowLayout) does not offer much flexibility."_ Actually, `FlowLayout` will keep the preferred sizes. But the OP is using `BorderLayout`, which will not. So you can try and set the preferred size all you want, and `BorderLayout` will keep laughing back at you :)

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, I noticed that after you updated your answer accordingly. (BTW: I consider it as a good practice to *not* create a `new JPanel()` and set its layout 20 lines later, but instead create a `new JPanel(withTheDesiredLayout)`, but nevertheless I should have read the question more thoroughly...)

Answer (score -2):

If you use Eclipse IDE,
add WindowBuilder Plugin and choose absolute layout and then set the layout what you want.
WindowBuilder is drag and drop swing ui component plugin.

Comment: You should really learn to hand code before trying to mess around with builder tools.